Can't use the python.h file; Python embedding error
I'm trying to automate sending messages on Telegram using Selenium and TeleBot library. However, I keep encountering the following error:
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'send_message'. 

How can I fix this? Here's my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from telebot import TeleBot

bot = TeleBot("your_token_here")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://web.telegram.org/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Log in']")
login_button.click()

phone_input = driver.find_element_by_name("phone_number")
phone_input.send_keys("your_phone_number")

next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Next']")
next_button.click()

bot.send_message(chat_id="your_chat_id", text="Hello, World!")

driver.quit()



Is there a reason you're using selenium for this? I'm not sure I see what purpose that serves. Telegram has an API and client libraries are readily available. I like using apprise for this kind of task, personally.

You didn't understand the use of TeleBot class from pyTelegramBotAPI.
It seems you are mixing Selenium automation with the bot's functionality to send a message. You should either send messages through pyTelegramBotApi or automate user interaction on the web interface using Selenium. You shouldn't use both simultaneously for sending a single message:
from telebot import TeleBot
bot = TeleBot("your_token")
def send_telegram_message(chat_id, message):
    try:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, message)
        print("Message sent.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send message: {str(e)}")
send_telegram_message("your_chat_id", "Hello, World!")

